# Issue function called x times button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing this problem that whenever user clicks "Click" couple times and then clicks on "SEND" it shows clicked times the message.

For example if the dialog opens 5 times it shows 5 times the message.
Facing this problem couple times something with binding how can i fix this i dont want to learn a quick fix.
But a good way to code things.

```js
var test = {
        init: function() {
            $(".toggle-dialog").on("click", function() {
                $(".picture-upload-dialog").toggle("fast", function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                        test2.uploadPicture()
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    },
    test2 = {
        uploadPicture: function() {
            var submitButton = $(".submit-picture");

            submitButton.on("click", function() {
                var fileVal = $("#fileToUpload").val();
                if (fileVal !== "") {
                    var ext = fileVal.split("."),
                        arrayExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp", "gif"];

                    console.log(fileVal)
                    ext = ext[ext.length - 1].toLowerCase();

                    if (arrayExtensions.lastIndexOf(ext) == -1) {
                        test3.errorMessage(001)
                    }
                } else {
                    test3.errorMessage(002)
                }
            })
        }
    },
    test3 = {
        errorMessage: function(type) {
            var error;
            switch (type) {
                case 001:
                    error = "< Ext error >"
                    break;
                case 002:
                    error = "< No picture selected. >"
                    break;
                default:
                    return "ERROR"
            }
            $(".error").append(error)
        }
    }

test.init();
```

```css
.picture-upload-dialog {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-dialog:hover {
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error">

</div>
<div class="public-text-input">
    <div class="text-options">
        <i class="toggle-dialog ct icon-picture" title="Upload...">Click</i>
        <div class="picture-upload-dialog">
            <div class="picture-upload-header">
                Upload your picture
            </div>
            <div class="picture-upload-content">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <button class="ct icon-picture submit-picture">SEND</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="color-picker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `text()` or `html()` instead of `append()`

Comment: `submitButton.on("click", function() {`  This will bind the click event every time you click `click`, just move the code to the init..

Comment: Is there a reason you want to rebind event handlers every time `uploadPicture` is invoked, instead of just doing it once when the page loads?

Comment: @charlietfl no it must be append, because it will be a div that need to be stay.

Comment: `But a good way to code things.`  Your code currently exposes 3 vars to global scope, when 0 would be better.   I'd also say a module loader / bundler is a good way to code things too.  But even without one, your code here could be restructured to be a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are calling `test2.uploadPicture()` every time it is visible, which in turn is adding one click handler every time "click" is clicked. Try the updated version:

```js
var test = {
        init: function() {
            test2.uploadPicture()
            $(".toggle-dialog").on("click", function() {
                $(".picture-upload-dialog").toggle("fast", function() {
                });
            });
        }
    },
    test2 = {
        uploadPicture: function() {
            var submitButton = $(".submit-picture");

            submitButton.on("click", function() {
                var fileVal = $("#fileToUpload").val();
                if (fileVal !== "") {
                    var ext = fileVal.split("."),
                        arrayExtensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp", "gif"];

                    console.log(fileVal)
                    ext = ext[ext.length - 1].toLowerCase();

                    if (arrayExtensions.lastIndexOf(ext) == -1) {
                        test3.errorMessage(001)
                    }
                } else {
                    test3.errorMessage(002)
                }
            })
        }
    },
    test3 = {
        errorMessage: function(type) {
            var error;
            switch (type) {
                case 001:
                    error = "< Ext error >"
                    break;
                case 002:
                    error = "< No picture selected. >"
                    break;
                default:
                    return "ERROR"
            }
            $(".error").append(error)
        }
    }

test.init();
```

```css
.picture-upload-dialog {
    display: none;
}

.toggle-dialog:hover {
    cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="error">

</div>
<div class="public-text-input">
    <div class="text-options">
        <i class="toggle-dialog ct icon-picture" title="Upload...">Click</i>
        <div class="picture-upload-dialog">
            <div class="picture-upload-header">
                Upload your picture
            </div>
            <div class="picture-upload-content">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <button class="ct icon-picture submit-picture">SEND</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="color-picker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just updated the answer to with a working code snippet.